# Centering 2 images with label in a row in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

The goal is that I want both images to have be side by side and centered in the middle of the row.

I tried to do that via adjusting the columns of the row

**The problem is that even with trying to center via rows, it always looks a little off center and if I change the max-width to be a little bigger, the images are no longer side by side and are on top of one another**

The height and width of the images are...

- graft1/graft2 - height="333" width="500"
- ivan1/ivan2 - height="542" width="400"

Here is my HTML

```
    <section class="wrapper style1">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="content">
                <!-- Content -->
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h2>Before and After</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="div_baPics">
                            <img id="graft1" class="baPics" src="images/graft1.jpg" alt="">
                            <label for="graft1">Before</label>
                            <img id="graft2" class="baPics" src="images/graft2.jpg" alt="">
                            <label for="graft2">After</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="div_baPics">
                            <img id="ivan1" class="baPics" src="images/ivan1.jpg" alt="">
                            <label for="ivan1">Before</label>
                            <img id="ivan2" class="baPics" src="images/ivan2.jpg" alt="">
                            <label for="ivan2">After</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And here is the CSS for baPics

```
.baPics {
    max-width: 30%;
}

    .div_baPics {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Could we get visual example ? With just that, it's kind of impossible to reproduce what's happening to you. It might also help if you specify the height and width of your images on the <img /> tag since we don't have them ;).

Comment: Sure I'll add them right now. But when I add height and width to my image tags, the images get super distorted

Comment: I guess but in this case, it's just so that we can imagine what space they're supposed to take, thus, the real height and width of them :).

Comment: I've updated the OP with the information

Comment: So the images should be side by side? Am I right? You want to produce a row with two images side by side?

Comment: Both images should be in just 1 `<div calss="row">`

Comment: Yes @GreenFox Both images are I believe? And then are also inside another div that should center it

Comment: Can I provide an example?

Comment: That would be fantastic. But I edited my code to do what you said but now the text isn't underneath the images. :O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74536/discussion-between-pshyoulost-and-green-fox).

Comment: @Bladepianist's answer is a good one I approved it.

Comment: @GreenFox Doesn't work =/

Comment: I did look into your template and it's not bootstrap-related at all. Thus the non working solution. I'd liked to help but I can't spend all day on it and most won't because they're misleaded (do we say it like that?) by your tags, just like me ;). I can nevertheless advise you to look for box centering inside another on Google ;). You'll find a lot of example and that might work with your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap, I went with its system. See this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/Bladepianist/55gyp94n/

Well, i did use real image so that you could see the result but with that (when I tested anyway), your image should resize, following the screen.

```
.thumbnail {
    border: none;
}
```

This code isn't needed, unless you don't want the border of the thumbnail ;).

Hope it will satisfy you and if that's the case, thumbs up :p.

Comment: May i have the entire code behind this rendering ? In some fiddle might be nice :). I'll look further into it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap img and corresponding label in a wrapper, like so:

```css
/*Just to make a difference between pics*/
body {
    background: grey;
}
/*Minimal CSS*/
.div_baPics {
    text-align: center; /*Center alignment for the wrapper*/
    font-size: 0; /*To remove the white space between pics*/
}
.pic {
    display: inline-block;
}
.pic img {
    display: block;
    /*This should be set by default by Bootstrap*/
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.pic label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px; /*Or whatever font-size you use*/
}
```

```html
<div class="div_baPics">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zNTWaR3.jpg" />
        <label>Pic 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IqiJN2f.png" />
        <label>Pic 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something isn't making any sense. Would you be down for teamviewing and looking at it? https://www.uploady.com/download/eKJsdXJfcfw/02JuQNiXk41f26fZ

Comment: There are parts of css I don't know. Something else is messing up the code then. A live site would solve that quickly.

http://i.imgur.com/XjwmH7u.png

Comment: I'm using the no-sidebar page of this html5up.net/arcana

Comment: Thats the exact render for the code provided, in Chrome. HTML + CSS
Look where I've inserted the CSS, somewhere at the bottom of your style.css.

HTML is exactly the same.

http://i.imgur.com/Ziq9RJC.png

Comment: I really don't know what to tell you :( You can find the website at http://mossaband.com/debbie/beforeandafter.html

Comment: Well, your css is scrambled, doesnt look like the original arcana theme anymore. Has some general attributes in your head area overriding stuff. This is not a bootstrap problem, not some image problem, is a general tidiness issue. Also, your HTML markup doesnt look like the one I've provided. There's no label, no wrappers as suggested. You don't even know what's in there. http://i.imgur.com/ovIhVEn.png